# Can absolute value functions be moved like this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

If I have an expression that looks like

$|x-a_1| + |x-a_2| + |x-a_3| + ... + |x-a_n|$

Is it the same as doing

$|nx - \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i|$

Comment: No, $\sum_i |x-a_i|\ne |nx-\sum_i a_i|$ in general.

Comment: Tried any example?

Answer (score 5):

No, in general you have only have by the triangular inequality

$|nx - \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i| \leq |x-a_1| + |x-a_2| + |x-a_3| + ... + |x-a_n| $

Sometimes you can have equality but to see that this isn't always true, just take, $n=2$, $x=0$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$. On one side you'll get $0$ and on the other you'll get $2$.

Answer (score 0):

No. For example $x=0, n=2, a_1=1, a_2=-2$:

- $|x-a_1| + |x-a_2| = |0-1| + |0+2| = 1+2=3$
- $|nx - \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i| = |0 -(1-2)| = |0+1| =1$